# AngularJS ngGrid text alignment

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

is there any way to align the cell text values to centre/right? Thank you.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O5llvsl2nS0OcRNU7XON) basic example.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As per [oblivion19's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804968/angularjs-nggrid-text-alignment#comment25981980_17806472), here is an example solution (with a little more context) by setting the `cellClass` property of a `columnDefs` object in `gridOptions`:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.someData = [{ "name": "MB", "age": 20 }, { "name": "KY", "age": 22 }];
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'someData',
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name',
        displayName: 'Name',
        cellClass: 'grid-align'
     }, {
        field: 'age',
        displayName: 'Age'
    }]
};
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid-align {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note that this solution only makes *some* columns centered (i.e., the ones with `cellClass` specified). To make *all* columns centered, simply add `class="grid-align"` to the `ng-grid` div instead.

Comment: Much easier than templating just for alignment and powerful too

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is. You want to use the row or cell template. It is defined on the columnDefs in the controller where you set up the ng-grid.

```
columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
                 {field:'age', displayName:'Age', cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{green: row.getProperty(col.field) > 30}"><div style="text-align:center;"  class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'}]
    };
```

I have an update Plunker below that has the columns aligned to the center.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nj3U19qoTAo4bs3O3Fjh?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I found that I could add cellClass to the column, and style that class with text-align. But your method works as well. Cheers!

Comment: I really think oblivion's answer is the best solution here.  No need to have a template just to set display properties.